# how to understand the result of xxd -d dumper?

Tags: unix, assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture, hardware

I studied many subjects from physics to logic gates to processor.
I also studied  computer architecture, compilers, Assembly x86,  operating systems, GPU, ....

All the subjects mentioned above, for some reasons  didn't cover  what is going "after an executable file being produced by compilers" downward the processor.

Please could  you provide me  with resources explain these things. because the way I am thinking drive me crazy if I didn't understand why things works the way they are working.

Like I want to understand for-example; why UNIX files start with 'elf'? if you tell me it 's convention. then  how  the computer as machine understand that a file start by 'elf' being passed to it?
It is a job of operating system. Then how the computer understand the code of operating system ?. I know that  processor will read it represented in Binary.
But how really the computer understand the binary? don't tell via transistors and logic gates. What I need to understand how the binary is being signaled to the computer hardware ? how to hardware is really being implemented to understand the binary?

Please any resources about this stage I mention above   share it with me ?

Comment: You might want to look at a course on operating system design/development. It should cover how the operating system is executed and how it loads and executes other executables. Recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic and your question too broad to reasonably answer here (I think). See for example https://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page though. Or maybe you even want some course on CPU architecture.

Comment: Other software is what understands metadata (and the "magic number", typically 4 bytes at the start of a file that identifies the format, e.g. an ELF executable or object file).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Format_indicators

Answer (score 0):

Binary is really just electrical signals and small charges stored in memory circuits. The binary data (ex:0101) is just a number represented with 2 symbols instead of 10 (like in base 10 or decimal). What matters, is the way you interpret those numbers to give them meaning.

For example, in processor architectures like x64, the developers of the architecture will create an instruction set that has a certain amount of instructions with a very specific format. The binary data thus becomes interpreted to be those instructions. Since the CPU is manufactured in its logic circuits to understand those instructions, then it can execute them by doing what they should according to the architecture.

The CPU is also configured to start executing at a specific address. The motherboard manufacturer puts machine code in binary at that address to kickstart the CPU. This is called the firmware. The OS developer will put its machine code on the hard-drive at a conventional position and in a conventional format so that the firmware can find and execute it.

Even in electrical terms there needs to be a conventional interpretation of signals. A certain chip on your motherboard might interpret 3V as a high signal and another might be 5V. What matters is that interconnected chips understand each other's interface. For example, an x64 processor might be connected to modern DDR4 RAM. The CPU knows that if it applies a signal (let's say 5V square wave 2600MHz) to certain pins of that chip then each oscillation will write or read data in the memory cells that are selected. It knows that because it expects the RAM module to follow the DDR4 standard. If the RAM module doesn't follow the standard then the CPU will not be able to interact with it.